# Injection between power sets implies an injection between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this came up in class and I have been thinking of an informal proof, what do you think:

Let A, B be sets. There exists an injection f between P(A) and P(B). Show there exists an injection g between A and B.

Idea:

I'll argue by contrapositive. So there is some a' in A such that there is no distinct a such that g(a) equals g(a').

So define f such that it takes {a} (except a') in P(A) to {g(a)} in P(B) and takes subsets of A {a1, a2,...} to a corresponding subset of B {g(a1), g(a2),...}.

Thus {a'} had nowhere unique to go, thus f cannot be objective. Thus the proof is complete.

I'm sure something is wrong, what do you think?

Comment: What your describing is *not* the negation of "there is no injection between $A$ and $B$"

Comment: This is independent of ZFC. It's consistent that there are sets $X, Y$ with $|X| < |Y|$ but $|\mathscr{P}(X)| = |\mathscr{P}(Y)|$.

Comment: Are your sets supposed to be finite?

Comment: No the sets are arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is false in general. It is consistent (with ZFC) that $2^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and then for any bijection $f$ from left to right, we cannot conclude that an injection between $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_0$ exists.

Comment: So where does my proof breakdown?